# Microcontroller to realize a wireless electrical switch - Suggestion

Tags: microcontroller, education

I hope this is the right place where ask my question.

I'm looking for a small microcontroller to realize a wireless electrical switch; can you suggest me any microcontroller to do this please?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please read the rules: product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: "*... can you suggest me any microcontroller ...*" Almost *any* microcontroller will do everything apart from the wireless part. Microcontrollers don't do wireless.

Comment: Hi @Transistor maybe i have to change my question; i need any little device ables to do what i said (the device should be cheap).

Comment: Hello @Oldfart i'm going to delete the question, but before can you or another user tell me where i can ask it please?

Comment: I don't know any website. I know, component selection is a lot of work because you have to work your way through manufactures websites. First determine the range you need, then look for ready made modules: PCB with controller and RF.

Comment: Thank you @Oldfart stack doesn't allow me to delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you need because more info is needed, but you should check ESP8266. This microcontroller comes with WIFI module.

Comment: Thats a good starting point for someone who just wants something to work - OP can look into a HC05 or something similar for Bluetooth, an nRF24L01 for 2.4GHz RF with 20 something channels, and some zigbee modules for zigbee. There's many wireless modules to add wireless capability to most MCUs

Comment: Hello @SHR thank you for your reply. Can i use the module you suggested alone or have i to link it to another device? The whole system should be able to enter in a 5x5x5 cm3 cube more or less or a rectangular small box.

Comment: Well, it depends. The ESP8266 has inputs and outputs. If you need to turn on and off an LED, you don't need to add any additional components. But if you need to control a higher voltage application, such as 120V, you need to add the relevant components (such as a relay and more).
Also, you will have to power it up, so some room for a battery needs to be taken into account.
The ESP8266 is relatively small, but you need to do the math to see if it fits your needs.